IDebugSymbols3::GetSymbolTypeIdWide fails the first time with a debugger output message and then succeeds
I'm using IDebugSymbols3::GetSymbolTypeIdWide to retrieve symbol details from my WinDbg extension. The code goes as such:
    HRESULT get_symbol_info(const CComPtr<IDebugSymbols3>& pDebugSymbols)
    {
        ULONG64 uiMod;
        ULONG uiStructTypeID;
        HRESULT hr = pDebugSymbols->GetSymbolTypeIdWide(
            L"wdf01000!FxObject", 
            &uiStructTypeID, &uiMod);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
             //Proceed
        }

        return hr;
    }

For some reason when I just attach to a kernel target with WinDbg and run it, the call to GetSymbolTypeIdWide prints the following to the command window in WinDbg:
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: wdf01000!FxObject                             ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

and GetSymbolTypeIdWide fails with the error code E_FAIL.
Then if I re-run the same code, it succeeds without any messages to the command window.
Two questions:

How do I stop it from outputting anything into the command window?

What am I doing wrong that it fails on the first run and succeeds on the following runs?



The simplest way to stop this output is to redirect the output stream for the WinDbg extension. You can use the OutputDebugString function to write messages to the debug output, and the OutputDebugString function can be redirected to a file or a different output stream

I think that the failure on the first run and success on subsequent runs suggests a symbol loading or initialization issue.WinDbg's symbol path needs to be correctly configured.

Is the type ID correct on second run? Is this related to lazy symbol loading? Try .symopt-0x04 and then run your command. Otherwise, symbol errors are typically only reported once and then ignored. Make sure you have your symbol path set correctly.

@ThomasWeller oh interesting. I didn't think about removing SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS. I was able to fix it by calling ReloadWide first with "/w wdf01000.sys" in this case.

@c00000fd: feel free to self-answer. I have no clue about those interfaces.
